# How to subtract value with next row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I want to calculation subtraction field energy with next value energy I just try with my query but I think result is still wrong

[image]

For my code

```
SELECT
    datapm.id,
    datapm.tgl,
    CONVERT ( CHAR ( 5 ),  datapm.stamp , 108 ) stamp,
    datapm.pmid,
    datapm.vavg,
    datapm.pf,
    ( CAST (datapm.energy AS FLOAT) -  (select top 1  CAST (energy AS FLOAT) from datapm as dt2 where dt2.id > datapm.id and dt2.tgl=datapm.tgl)) as energy
FROM
    datapm
GROUP BY
    datapm.id,
    datapm.tgl,
    datapm.stamp,
    datapm.pmid,
    datapm.vavg,
    datapm.pf,
    datapm.energy
    ORDER BY tgl desc
```

My sample

```
id  pmdi        tgl         stamp               vavg    pf     energy
787 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  06:00:00.0000000    407.82  0.98    1408014.25
788 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  07:00:00.0000000    403.31  0.85    1408041.00
789 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  08:00:00.0000000    408.82  0.87    1408081.75
```

Result I want

```
id  pmdi        tgl         stamp               vavg    pf     energy
787 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  06:00:00.0000000    407.82  0.98    -2.675
788 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  07:00:00.0000000    403.31  0.85    -4.075
789 SDPEXT_2    2021-09-06  08:00:00.0000000    408.82  0.87    -11.012
```

Comment: What is the actual formula/calculation for the energy column?

Comment: How did you get `-2.675` ? can you show the calculation ?

Comment: just like my picture first row energy substraction next row energy

Comment: i will edit my question

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

remove the `GROUP BY` in your query, you are not using any aggregate function

If `energy` is already in numeric data type, don't convert to `float`.

use `LEAD()` to get the next row value

```
SELECT . . .
       (d.energy - LEAD (d.energy) OVER (PARTITION BY d.tgl
                                             ORDER BY d.id)) / 10
FROM  datapm d
```

not sure what is the actual formula, but looking at the result, you need to divide by 10 to obtain it